# Setting NULL values to a custom value in Access-SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, ms-access-2003

When LEFT JOINing two tables, is there a way to set the cells which can not be matched (NULL) to a custom value? So e.g. when the result returns, the NULL-cells actually HAVE a value, e.g. "N/A" or "Not found"?

I want to do this in MS Access 2003

---

Example:

```
| id | value |               | id | other value |
|----|-------|   LEFT JOIN   |----|-------------|
| 1  | hello |   -- id -->   | 2  | world       |
| 2  | you   |

results in:

| id | value | other value |
| 1  | hello | NULL        |
| 2  | you   | world       |

but should be:

| id | value | other value |
| 1  | hello | custom-val  |
| 2  | you   | world       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Nz()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx) to substitute an arbitrary value for a  `NULL`;

```
SELECT Nz(F, "Not Present") FROM T
```

Would return either the value of field `F`, or `"Not Present"` if `F` were `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that SQL’s outer join is a kind of relational union which is explicitly designed to project null values. You want to avoid using the null value (a good thing too, in my opinion), therefore you should avoid using outer joins. Note that modern relational languages have dispensed with the concept of null and outer join entirely (see endnote).

This outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.id, T1.value, T2.other_value
  FROM T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
          ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

…is semantically equivalent to this SQL code:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.value, T2.other_value
  FROM T1
       INNER JOIN T2
          ON T1.id = T2.id
UNION
SELECT T1.id, T1.value, NULL
  FROM T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM T2
                    WHERE T1.id = T2.id
                  );
```

The second query may look long winded but that’s only because of the way SQL has been designed/evolved. The above is merely a natural join, a union and a semijoin. However, SQL has no semijoin operator, requires you to specify column lists in the `SELECT` clause and to write `JOIN` clauses if your product hasn’t implemented Standard SQL’s `NATURAL JOIN` syntax (Access hasn’t), which results in a lot of code to express something quite simple.

Therefore, you could write code such as the second query above but using an actual default value rather than the null value.

---

The only relational game in town is the specification of a D language know as "The Third Manifesto" by Chris Date and Hugh Darwen. It explicitly rejects Codd's nulls (latterly Codd proposed two kinds of null) doesn't accommodate an outer join operator (in more recent writings the authors have proposed relation-valued attributes as an alternative to outer join). Specific citations:

C. J. Date (2009): SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code: Ch 4,  'A remark on outer join' (p.84)

Darwen, Hugh (2003): The Importance of Column Names: "Note that in Tutorial D, the only 'join' operator is called JOIN, and it means 'natural join'." (p.16)

C. J. Date and Hugh Darwen (2006): Databases, Types and the Relational Model: The Third Manifesto: Proscription 4: "D shall include no concept of a 'relation' in which some 'tuple' includes some 'attribute' that does not have a value."

Comment: Citation for "modern relational languages have dispensed with the concept of null and outer join entirely", please?

Comment: Wouldn't your second query be more efficient with UNION ALL, since the two resultsets are entirely disjunct?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Citations added as requested.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "Wouldn't your second query be more efficient with...?" -- here's another quote from on one of those aforementioned citations: "Why should I, as a user, have to devote time and effort to figuring out whether some DISTINCT is going to be a performance hit and whether it's logically safe to omit it?" C. J. Date (2009): SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code, p.78.

Comment: The relational database theory that went into designing the RDBMS's that we all use is already far enough from reality. Seems to me that until we have actual implementations of these new theories, they are not much more than "interesting" (if that).

Comment: As to whether or not a user of a relational database should have to ask whether one of two equivalent operations is more efficient, it seems to me that in an ideal world, of course not! But we live in the REAL WORLD, where database engines are imperfect implementations of theory and where query optimizers don't always reach expected results. So, to me, it's not an unreasonable question to ask, though the answer could be different for different database engines.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: funny but I find your question, "Wouldn't your second query be more efficient...?" to be a theoretical one. With my test data, change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` makes absolutely no difference. Is the optimizer being smart or is my test data not 'real world' enough? The OP hasn't posted their data so your question is unanswerable. But this isn't meant to be taken to seriously. I acknowledge your point about `UNION ALL` is a valid one.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: As regards new theories, if we don't ask, we don't get. I try to do my bit to get the features I want implemented in the product of my choosing. Just because those same vendors provide functionality that is not to my taste (NULL and the operators that generate them) doesn't mean I have to use them. Again, I make these points lightly, please don't take offence.